# Can one of the parameters of formData include an object?

Tags: javascript, laravel

Can one of the parameters of formData include an object?

If I do the following, the object will be turned into a string on the server side.

```
  formData.append('first_name', 'takuya');
  formData.append('last_name', 'yamamoto');
  formData.append('favorite', {color: 'red', sports: "tennis"});
```

I'm using Laravel.

If I do the following, it will be changed to the string [object Object].

```
$request->file('favorite')
```

Comment: http(s) can transfer textual data only, hence live objects are not transferred. You can stringify the object to JSON.

Comment: I did not know that. Thank you for teaching me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. But you can convert the object to a JSON string and then decode it in your backend. It would look something like this:

```js
formData.append('favorite', JSON.stringify({color: 'red', sports: "tennis"}));
```

In your controller:

```php
$favorite = json_decode($request('favorite'));
```

Comment: It went well! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

in JS Part :

```
formData.append('favorite', JSON.stringify({color: 'red', sports: "tennis"}));
```

In PHP Part (Controller)

```
$favorite = json_decode($request('favorite'));
```

Comment: It went well! Thank you!